# git - extend commit hook with part of branch name

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket, githooks

I would like to use the *prepare-commit-msg* hook. I am using feature and bugfix branches (feature/ISSUEKEY-23123-some-feature) and I would like to prepend the ISSUEKEY-23123 into the commit message:

```
#!/bin/bash
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
STR=`echo $BRANCH_NAME | grep -E 'ISSUEKEY-[0-9]*' -o`
if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == *"feature"* ]] || [[ $BRANCH_NAME == *"bugfix"* ]]
then
    echo $STR > $1
fi
```

This works, but it discards the standard message vi is showing me for commits, e.g.:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Explicit paths specified without -i or -o; assuming --only paths...
# On branch feature/ISSUEKEY-1716-model-implement
# Your branch is based on 'origin/feature/ISSUEKEY-1716-model-implement', but the upstream is gone.
#   (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   asd
#
# Untracked files:
#       FSTD-1716
#       TMP
#
```

Is there a way to either prepend the `STR` to the output, or to call a git command what prints me the mentioned standard commit message?

The opened commit message should be:

```
ISSUEKEY-1716 
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Explicit paths specified without -i or -o; assuming --only paths...
# On branch feature/ISSUEKEY-1716-model-implement
# Your branch is based on 'origin/feature/ISSUEKEY-1716-model-implement', but the upstream is gone.
#   (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       new file:   asd
#
# Untracked files:
#       FSTD-1716
#       TMP
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
COMMIT_MSG=`echo $BRANCH_NAME | grep -E 'ISSUEKEY-[0-9]*' -o`
if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == *"feature/"* ]] || [[ $BRANCH_NAME == *"bugfix/"* ]]
then
    PRE_COMMIT_MSG=$(cat $1)
    if [ -z "$COMMIT_MSG" ] ; then
        exit 0
    else
        COMMIT_MSG="$COMMIT_MSG - $PRE_COMMIT_MSG"
        echo "$COMMIT_MSG" > $1
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [the githooks documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_prepare_commit_msg):

> This hook is invoked by *git commit* right after preparing the default log message, and before the editor is started. ... The purpose of the hook is to **edit the message file in place**, and ...

(boldface mine).  This means you must do just what it says: edit the file in place.  Don't just overwrite it!  Hence, instead of:

```
echo $STR > $1
```

you might do:

```
ed - "$1" << end
0a
$STR
.
w
q
end
```

which runs the `ed` editor on a "here document" script consisting of instructions to add the expansion of `$STR` after line 0, then write that and exit the editor.  (You can use any editor; `sed` is popular here as well.)

As an aside, don't do this:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git branch | grep '*' | sed 's/* //')
```

since it's overly dependent on various "porcelain" command output styles.  Instead, use `git symbolic-ref` (usually the preferred method for scripts) or `git rev-parse`.  The difference between these two is a bit philosophical:

- `git symbolic-ref <options> HEAD` gets you the name of the branch you are currently on, or fails if you are on the special anonymous "detached HEAD" case.  (The `<options>` you would want here is just `--short` to omit the `refs/heads/` prefix.)
- `git rev-parse <options> HEAD` is mostly guaranteed to produce a successful name of some sort, since `HEAD` is *always* a valid name<sup>1</sup> and therefore will correspond to *something*.  It's meant to turn `HEAD` into a revision hash ID, but with the `--symbolic` option it will leave a name "as symbolic as possible" and with `--abbrev-ref` it will also leave out `refs/heads/` when it does so.

The key difference is that the `rev-parse` method does not fail when HEAD is "detached", while the `symbolic-ref` method does.  The failure lets you distinguish this case, which is sometimes important.  For your purposes it's not so important and when using `symbolic-ref` you need a fallback for the "no name for current branch" detached HEAD case.

Hence, you want either:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

or:

```
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD || echo HEAD)
```

(curiously, these are exactly the same number of bytes of command).

---

<sup>1</sup>There's one corner case here.  While `HEAD` *is* always valid—if it's not valid, you don't have a Git repository (Git will give you a "fatal:" message to that effect)—if you are on an "unborn branch", `HEAD` is a symbolic reference to a branch name that does not exist.  In this particular case, `git symbolic-ref` will *succeed* and `git rev-parse HEAD` will *fail*, which is backwards from the more usual case of a detached HEAD.